can someone please explain the order of execution in pytest when the same fixture is used for every function
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
I am using the above fixture in my test framework in every file. But I don't understand in which order the functions are getting executed and why only in that specific order the tests are getting executed. If we can define the order of functions then please tell me in which file should I define the order.
I have checked the pytest.ini file and the files related to pytest. But didn't found any useful information.The functions will be auto invoked without any function call. So, please clarify the behaviour.
We are not using any order fixtures also.

Can you please explain what it is you would like to achieve? The order of the tests should not matter at all. Never. If you write proper unit tests for your code base, they should always pass, no matter in what order you are running them.
So, why does the order matter to you? And does a fixture solve?

Files are ordered as they discovered in file structure and test functions in those files are run in the order as they defined with in the file.
To modify it, you can use a hook in conftest.py:
@pytest.hookimpl()
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    # Modification to order tests alphabetically
    items.sort(key=lambda x: x.name)

